# How a Home Button works

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have a input device with a home button which opens my default browser. According to my hardware keylogger it is not sending any keystroke which the keylogger recognises. How is this opening my default browser and how can I change what it does?

This is the input device in question
http://www.wechipbox.com/wechip-r2-air-remote24g-wireless-backlit-voice-remote-with-key-p-623.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

I needed to remap the 'browser home Virtual-Key Code' to the keyboard shortcut which triggers the desired behaviour.

I used PowerToys for this